# Filter the Dictionary With Array value

Tags: ios, arrays, filtering

I have Array which contain ID like

```
var ID = ["782", "783", "784", "785", "786", "788", "789", "790", "791", "792", "793", "795", "805"]
```

And One Arr Of Dictionary like

```
Var arr2 = [["ID":"782","AmenitiesURL":"xyx.com"],["ID":"783","AmenitiesURL":"xybx.com"],["ID":"784","AmenitiesURL":"xyax.com"]]
```

Aslo see in image. Now I want to get the url of the ID.

Ex. if arr `ID`= `784` Then i want find that `ID` in the `arr2` and get their `url` and append in New array,

In short Two array one is for `ID` and other for `URL`.

[image]

Comment: Change the dictionary array to a struct array. IMO you should never be having the dict array in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the URL of a specific id

```
let id = "784"
if let dict = arr2.first(where: { $0["ID", default:""] == id }), let urlString = dict["AmenitiesURL"] {
    print(urlString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that working using the following approach:

```
let urls = ID.compactMap { (id) in
    return arr2.first(where: {$0["ID"] == id})?["AmenitiesURL"]
}
```

**Output:**

```
print(urls) //["xyx.com", "xybx.com", "xyax.com"]
```

For all the ids in `ID array`, you'll get `AmenitiesURL` values from `arr2 array`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Though this one retains the structure of arr2

```
let filteredArray = arr2.filter { dict -> Bool in
    for id in ID{
        if dict["ID"] == id{
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```